# Issue adding more than one hosted service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have run into a small problem and could use some help. I have 2 hosted services I am trying to add to my Blazor Server application. These are both long-running background services which create websocket connections and hold them open to receive data. The issue is that only the first service is starting. The second service does start but only for a brief moment when I shutdown the application and a couple log messages flash briefly at the last second. Both services have StartAsync and StopAsync.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Service1>();
            services.AddSingleton<Service1>(p => p.GetServices<IHostedService>().OfType<Service1>().Single());
            services.AddHostedService<Service2>();
            services.AddSingleton<Service2>(p => p.GetServices<IHostedService>().OfType<Service2>().Single());
        });
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or maybe it's not possible to have 2 services running at the same time?

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**
I am using AddSingleton as I am injecting the instance into some of my webpages in order to access public properties I set within the service so the data can be displayed on the webpage.

The services are large so I don't want to paste all the code. Basically the gist of them are:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //Connect to websocket streams and handle incoming data

    while (true)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't magically know what Service1 and 2 are doing, we need to see code to be able to understand what's going on.

Comment: why are you trying to add singletons with `services.AddSingleton`? `services.AddHostedService` is enough by itself

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry I didn't think it was necessary to include them as my question is more about running the two services simultaneously which does not seem to be happening.

Comment: @abdusco I inject the instance into some of my razor pages in order to access public properties to get information from the services to display on the web pages.

Comment: You need to confirm for us that the StartAsync methods return timely.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have updated the original post

Comment: You're creating multiple Service1 and Service2 instances with the current code (1 each time GetServices is resolved, 1 more for the Transient call). Whatever you're doing with the razor pages is completely wrong and you need to find another way to do it. The updated question doesn't help at all, by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure about the AddSingleton() part but that is not the direct issue. The symptom you describe (Service2 starting when Service1 stops) fits the while(true) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while(true) {...}` pattern is not supported.

You will have to start a Timer, Thread or longrunning Task.

StartAsync must return quickly, the Services are started sequentially.

This works, with multiple Services:

```
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task.Run(Forever);  // dont pass the cancellationToken
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Forever()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5_000);
        }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {                    
    }
```

Or look up the `BackgroundService` base class. Which does the above but probably better.

Comment: Thank you Henk! Appreciate the help. Follow up question if you don't mind. I have data within the service/task that I need to be able to access within the webpages. Currently the solution to that is to use AddSingleton and then inject the instance of the service into the webpage where I can access the public properties exposed from the service and the webpage reads that data. If I run these services as a task, I'm not able to access that data in the same way. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Tldr: Websocket data in service, need a way to access the data to display on webpage.

Comment: Use a dedicated Repository. Use a singleton and inject it into the Service and the Page. Make sure it's Thread-safe.

Comment: About [injecting into a Bg Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)